# Laravel migration error: Cannot declare class OpeningHoursToMallTable, because the name is already in use

Tags: migration, laravel-8, multi-tenant

I made a migration in Laravel 8 and it throws me an error

> Cannot declare class OpeningHoursToMallTable, because the name is
> already in use

I am sure the name is unique. How is that possible and how to avoid. The only thing it could be the reason is that project has multitenacy package istalled, so there are more than one database. But thats no reason to throws this errors. Thanks for any help.